# No me reconoce el CSS

Tags: javascript, css, hover, img, gatsby

Gatsby js no me reconoce el css cuando lo mando llamar

```js
<img src={economia} width='150' height='150' class='trans' alt='economia'/>
```

Acá esta mi hoja de estilo

```css
.trans {
    transition: transform .3s;
    }
    .trans:hover {
    transform: scale(1.1);
    }
```

No se porque dejo de reconocerlo de un momento para otro porque antes si me funcionaba el hover en la imagen cuando pasaba el mouse por ella, alguien puede ayudarme

Comment: Puedes inspeccionar en la consola del navegador para saber si hay otros estilos siendo aplicados y tengan precedencia sobre ese

Comment: @Alfabravo Ya hice eso y no hay ningún otro estilo sobre ese, no se que suceda

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Encontre la solución a mi pregunta. Para que en gatsby js me reconozca los estilos, en mi caso tengo un css con estilos globales para las imagenes, se tiene que agregar la ruta en el archivo de nombre **gatsby-browser.js** como el siguiente ejemplo

```
import './src/pages/components/imagen.css';
```

De esa forma se manda a llamar como de costumbre `class='nombre de tu css'` y ya puede reconocer el estilo

Answer (score 2):

Deberia funcionar a menos que alguna otra regla CSS este sobreescribiendo `transform: scale(1.1);`, podria ser otro `transform`.

Inpecciona el elemento con el debugger y revisa si hay otras reglas CSS ahi.

```css
.trans {
    transition: transform .3s;
}
.trans:hover {
    transform: scale(1.1);
}
```

```html
<img src={economia} width='150' height='150' class='trans' alt='economia'
```